# Vue3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token appears in the browser console whenever I reload the page

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-router, vite, vue-typescript

I am building a website using Vue3, Typescript, Vue router and vite. The app is hosted on an Apache web server. The app builds successfully and works as intended on my local machine.

However, when I move the build to the production server it breaks when the page reloads with the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` which is coming from the js file that Vue builds. When I take a look at where the error is, it's not human readable. Also when this error happens the web page just shows a blank screen.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "enigma-vue",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon": "^38.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block": "^38.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^38.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline": "^38.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.5",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^5.11.2",
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.7.13",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "dropzone": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "flat": "^5.0.2",
    "highlight.js": "^11.6.0",
    "js-beautify": "^1.14.6",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
    "litepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "lucide": "^0.90.0",
    "lucide-vue-next": "^0.95.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.23",
    "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^3.2.0",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.9",
    "tabulator-tables": "^5.3.4",
    "tiny-slider": "^2.9.4",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.7",
    "toastify-js": "^1.12.0",
    "tom-select": "^2.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vue3-dropzone": "^2.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zoom-vanilla.js": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@types/dropzone": "^5.7.8",
    "@types/flat": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/js-beautify": "^1.13.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.3",
    "@types/tabulator-tables": "^5.4.8",
    "@types/toastify-js": "^1.11.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "postcss": "^8.4.25",
    "postcss-advanced-variables": "^3.0.1",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^12.0.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.13.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.4.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.4"
  }
}
```

**Vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: ["tailwind.config.js", "node_modules/**"],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["tailwind-config"],
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        "tailwind-config": path.resolve(__dirname, "./tailwind.config.js"),
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src") 
      },
  },
  base: '/'
})
```

**Index.html file generated by vite**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <base href="/" />
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-2c92196c.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-14613a76.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Image of the error code at the bottom and the blank page it produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7G3u.png)

So far I've tried:

- Removing the .htaccess file to see if that was causing issues
- Adding `<base href="/" />` to the index.html file as was recommended in a similar ticket
- Changing the Vue Router history to see if that was the issue
- Removing and adding the base path option in the vite.config.ts

All of these changes had no effect on the error.

I have tested it on:

- Google Chrome
- Brave
- Edge
- FireFox - I get a slightly different error Uncaught SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

I would really appreciate any help as I am at a loss with this one.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's tough to tell without being able to inspect the JS that Vite is generating (the `/assets/index-2c92196c.js` file). Can you maybe post just the first part of that file? Or link to it in a Gist?

Comment: Of course, here is the JS file [link](https://gist.github.com/CJConnor/31699a701d42906d31f924cfa012f5fd) @GregL

Comment: See [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/minification-produces-invalid-javascript/406236) thread, seems relevant.

Comment: Basically something is re-minifying your code after Vite has minified it first, and that is causing a syntax error. In the above thread it was Cloudflare. Are you using Cloudflare or a different CDN that may be minifying your code?

Comment: Wow thank you Yitz! I was able to changed the extension on the js file to .min.js so Cloudflare would ignore it and it worked! :) Thank you so much, been bothering me for a whole week!

Comment: @Yitz You should add that as an answer, so that it can be more easily found in the future. CJ can then accept the answer and everyone wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message points to the (invalid) code `1.toString` in your javascript file. By searching for this text and 'syntax error' I found [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/minification-produces-invalid-javascript/406236) thread.

It seems that something is re-minifying your code after Vite has minified it first, and that is causing a syntax error. In the above thread it was Cloudflare.

Try disabling the Cloudflare minification and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Following this help me solve white page problem on my react app also. Tks